# Doctrine Migration class not found error when attempting to run down/rollback command

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-migrations

When I run `bin/console doctrine:migrations:list` I see the Migration listed as:

`Application\Migrations\Version20210909072642`

I am attempting to rollback a migration and I have tried a few different versions:

```
bin/console --env=dev doctrine:migrations:execute 'Application\DoctrineMigrations\Version20210909072642' --down --no-interaction -vvv
bin/console --env=dev doctrine:migrations:execute Version20210909072642 --down --no-interaction -vvv
bin/console --env=dev doctrine:migrations:execute 20210909072642 --down --no-interaction -vvv
```

Has this feature changed with a recent [DoctrineMigrationsBundle](https://symfony.com/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/current/index.html) update?

Every time I run it I get the following error:

```
In MigrationClassNotFound.php line 15:
                                                          
  [Doctrine\Migrations\Exception\MigrationClassNotFound]  
  Migration class "20210909072642" was not found?
```

My Doctrine config looks like this:

```
doctrine_migrations:
    migrations_paths:
        'Application\Migrations': 'app/DoctrineMigrations'
    storage:
        table_storage:
            table_name: 'migration_versions'
```

Comment: Are you certain about the namespace `Application\DoctrineMigrations\Version20210909072642`?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Yes, I was able to run the `:migrate` without any issues

Comment: You could try `Application\Migrations\Version20210909072642` since the `migrations_paths` in your configuration sets the namespace your migration is located under as `Application\Migrations` and not `Application\DoctrineMigrations`

Comment: Thank you @OluwafemiSule - that was the issue. A PEBKAC issue, I think :-) Feel free to submit as the answer and I shall accept.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`migrations_paths`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/3.0/reference/configuration.html#configuration) in your configuration sets the namespace your migration is located under as `Application\Migrations` and not `Application\DoctrineMigrations`.

Run the migrate command with `Application\Migrations\Version20210909072642`.

```php
bin/console --env=dev doctrine:migrations:execute \
'Application\Migrations\Version20210909072642' --down --no-interaction -vvv
```

Answer (score 11):

Sorry to dig up this post, but I had a similar concern with Symfony 6.

I did a test migration, and I had the same problem.

Here my migration list

```
+------------------------------------------+----------+---------------------+----------------+-------------+
| Migration Versions                                                                         |             |
+------------------------------------------+----------+---------------------+----------------+-------------+
| Migration                                | Status   | Migrated At         | Execution Time | Description |
+------------------------------------------+----------+---------------------+----------------+-------------+
| DoctrineMigrations\Version20220922124029 | migrated | 2022-09-22 14:41:13 | 3.352s         |             |
+------------------------------------------+----------+---------------------+----------------+-------------+
```

When i use the command `php bin/console d:m:e --down --no-interaction DoctrineMigrations\Version20220922124029`
I got the error message:

```
In MigrationClassNotFound.php line 15:
Migration class "DoctrineMigrationsVersion20220922124029" was not found?
```

Here the `\` is escaped, so we have to use the `\\` instead, like:
`d:m:e --down --no-interaction DoctrineMigrations\\Version20220922124029`

and now i got `[notice] Executing DoctrineMigrations\Version20220922124029 down` working.

Hope it helps someone in same case.

Comment: In Symfony 6.1.*, the use of the 2nd \ seems not needed anymore. At least in my case, "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.7", and "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.2",, I could simply use this command and it worked: php bin/console doctrine:migrations:execute DoctrineMigrations\Version20230118204719  --down

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem:

```
Migration class "20221124124122" was not found?
```

And was solved when i ran:

1. `php bin/console d:m:list` (To know how the interface see my migrations);
2. `php bin/console d:m:execute 'DoctrineMigrations\VersionYYYYMMDDSSxxx' --up` (To migrate the version. Remember to put the version in quotes).

Answer (score 0):

I also got the error "`Migration class "Version20230530204858" was not found?`" when I launhed `bin/console doctrine:migrations:execute --down DoctrineMigrations\Version20230530204858`.

I added second slash just like here `bin/console doctrine:migrations:execute --down DoctrineMigrations\\Version20230530204858`
After that it worked.